# Get ValueError when calling tf.image.non_max_suppression

Tags: tensorflow, nms

I want to use tensorflow tf.image.non_max_suppression function.

I tried both snippets below:

```
indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
    boxes=anchors_fit, 
    scores=rpn_cls_prob,
    max_output_size=self.max_outputs_num, 
)
```

```
indices,scores = tf.image.non_max_suppression_with_scores(
    boxes=anchors_fit, 
    scores=rpn_cls_prob,
    max_output_size=self.max_outputs_num, 
)
```

where `anchors_fit.shape` is `[36864,4]`
and `rpn_cls_prob.shape` is `[36864]`

Both calls raise:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'non_max_suppression_with_scores/NonMaxSuppressionV5' (op: 'NonMaxSuppressionV5') with input shapes: [36864,4], [36864], [1], [], [], [].
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the shape of `self.max_outputs_num`?

From [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/non_max_suppression?version=stable):

> **`max_output_size`**: A scalar integer Tensor representing the maximum number of boxes to be selected by non max suppression.

Here, it seems to be an 1-D array, as the error message report it between brackets.
Moreover, it would match the error message, as a scalar has a rank 0 and a 1-D array as a rank 1.

Thus, you should probably convert your `self.max_outputs_num` from an array to a scalar.